# Expand php pdo to support impala, but the setAttribute() function failed

Tags: php, pdo, impala

Expand php pdo to support impala, but the setAttribute() function failed.
My code is:

```
class ImpalaPDO extends PDO {

    public function __construct($dsn, $username, $passwd, $options)
    {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $passwd, $options);
        $impala = new ImpalaPDOStatement();
        $impala->test();
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('ImpalaPDOStatement', array($this)));
    }
}

class ImpalaPDOStatement extends PDOStatement {

    public function test() {
        print "aaa";
    }
}
```

The error message is:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS requires format array(classname, array(ctor_args)); the classname must be a string specifying an existing class.
What I can confirm is ImpalaPDOStatement is existing, because $impala->test() print a string successfully. So I don't know what the error message mean.

Comment: Your `ImpalaPDOStatement` should extend `PDOStatement` first. After it does that, try again and debug any further problems.

Comment: @Mjh, I am sorry I forget to copy the original code, I paste the modified code. I had extends PDOStatement, but the error message is always all the same. Do you hava other suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must override protected constructor of `PDOStatement`:

```
class ImpalaPDOStatement extends PDOStatement {
    public $dbh;

    // Constructor must be overrided
    protected function __construct($dbh) {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }

    public function test() {
        print "aaa";
    }
}
```